# trying to learn how to error check my code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to ask the user for two two-digit numbers and then perform a length check and a type check on both of the numbers, then I want to output the sum of the numbers. Here's what I have so far:

```
package codething;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a two digit number (10-99) ");
        int n = number.nextInt();

                if(number.hasNextInt()) {
                } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
                }

        int m;



        int length = String.valueOf(number).length();
        if (length == 2) {           
        } else {
           System.out.println("this isnt a valid input and you have killed my program ;(");
        }

        Scanner number1 = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter another two digit number (10-99) ");
                        m = number.nextInt();

                    if(number1.hasNextInt()) {
                        m = number1.nextInt();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }

        int sum = n + m;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }   
}
```

At the moment my program won't even ask me for my second input. Not sure what to do :/

Comment: Maybe you wanted `m = number1.nextInt();` instead of `m = number.nextInt();`? (after printing "Enter another two digit number (10-99) ")

Comment: Don't use two `Scanner` objects to read from `System.in`

Comment: how do you input your digits? I mean smth like `99 10` or `99<enter>10`?

Comment: I will correct that now but i'm not even receiving the prompt to enter the number yet...

Comment: Why are you using `number.hasNextInt()`? If say the validation for the first number fails, then what?

Comment: GBlodgett what should I set the 2nd one to read from then?

Comment: to check if its an integer, how else could I do that?

Comment: Heard of regex? There are many ways to do this. FYI, `number.hasNextInt()` doesn't check if the input is numeric, where'd you get that idea from?

Comment: could you elaborate? im a newbie :)

Comment: @LucasEstefanos I'm not sure what @Nicholas K is going for, but `hasNextInt()` is the right way to check whether the next thing in `System.in` is an `int` - you don't need to complicate things with a regex. `System.in` will handle the number parsing for you with `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()`, that's what it's for

@GBlodgett meant that you shouldn't use **two** `Scanner` objects to read from `System.in` - in general, one source of input (an input `Stream` is the technical term) should have one `Scanner` reading from it - you can use the same `Scanner` to read from the same stream many times

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Thanks for clearing it up a bit more, so your saying I only need 1 scanner to read from the data?

Comment: @LucasEstefanos correct. **If** you had two separate input streams (say one reading user input, and one reading a text file), then you would use a separate scanner for each. This is basically because Scanners consume the thing they're scanning, so using two scanners at the same time on the same input can cause them to interfere with each other. E.g. for `scanner1` and `scanner2` operating on the same stream, `scanner1.hasNextInt()` returning `true` doesn't guarantee that the next `scanner1.nextInt()` will succeed **if** `scanner2.nextInt()` is called in between

Comment: Checking that the string representation of a number is has length two doesn't guarantee it is in the range 10-99: -9 to -1 also have string representations with length 2. It is far easier better (and faster) to check `number >= 10 && number <= 99`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So several things:

-Don't construct more than one `Scanner` objects to read from `System.in`. It just causes problems.

-You're using `String.valueOf()` to convert an int to a `String`. It is better to simply check to make sure it is between 10 and 99.

-You check to make sure that the `Scanner` has a next int *after* you call `nextInt` which won't help. You need to make sure that there is a next int.

-A lot of your `if` statements have an empty `if` block and then you do something in the else. You can just do the opposite in the `if` and omit the `else` (Instead of `if(length ==2) {}` you can do `if(length != 2) {//code}`

```
Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
System.out.println("Enter a two digit number (10-99) ");
int n = 0;
 if(number.hasNextInt()) {
     n = number.nextInt();
 } else {
    number.next();  //Clear bad input
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}

int m = 0;


if ( n< 10 || n > 99) {           
   System.out.println("this isnt a valid input and you have killed my program ;(");
}


System.out.println("Enter another two digit number (10-99) ");
if(number.hasNextInt()) {
     m = number.nextInt();
} else {
    number.next();
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}

if (n< 10 || n > 99) {           
    System.out.println("this isnt a valid input and you have killed my program ;(");
}        
int sum = n + m;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: This will break if I input "abc"

Comment: @GBlodgett Thank you <3

Comment: "You're using String.valueOf() to convert an int to a String. You want Integer.toString()" given that the former delegates to the latter, this makes no meaningful difference. However, since OP is trying to use this to ensure that the number is in the range 10-99 (which it doesn't), converting to string is not the right approach anyway

Comment: @AndyTurner I corrected my post. Thanks for the suggestion!